# When can't an object be converted to a reference?

Tags: c++, gcc, reference

I want to compile the following line of code from http://code.google.com/p/enhsim:

```
enh::eout << enh::setw(26);
```

gcc gives the following error:

```
error: no match for 'operator<<' in 'enh::eout << enh::setw(26)'
```

But the `EnhSimOutput` class (of which `enh::eout` is an instance) does declare:

```
EnhSimOutput& operator<< (setw& p);
```

This problem goes away if I implement a version of the operation that accepts the object by value:

```
EnhSimOutput& operator<< (setw p);
```

or if I create the `enh::setw` object as a local, i.e.:

```
enh::setw wValue(26);
enh::eout << wValue;
```

My question is this: why does gcc not select the "by-reference" version of the operator to begin with?

The developers who wrote this code clearly made it compile, yet default gcc refuses to do it. Why is there a difference between an object declared separately as a local variable and a local created inline?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The value `enh::setw(26);` is an *rvalue* . Actually, temporaries like that are rvalues. Rvalues have special properties. One of them is that their address can't be taken (`&enh::setw(26);` is illegal), and they can't generally bind to references to non-const (some temporaries *can* bind to references to non-const, but these undergo special rules: Calling member functions on temporary objects and catching exception objects by reference to non-const. In the latter case, the temporary even is an *lvalue*).

There are two kind of expressions: **lvalues** that denote objects (that in turn may store an value) or functions, and **rvalues** which are meant to represent values read out of an object or represented by temporaries, numeral literals and enumerator constants. In C++03, to be able to pass such values to a function that accepts its value by-reference, there is a rule that they can be accepted by reference-to-const: `setw const& p` would accept it. That is, you would have to declare your operator like this:

```
EnhSimOutput& operator<< (setw const& p);
```

That's a bit unfortunate, because you can't disambiguate constant lvalues (objects you created on the stack using `const enh::setw e(26);` for example) and non-const or const rvalues (like `enh::setw(26);` which is a non-const temporary). Also, if you go by that, the parameter can't have called non-const member functions on it, because it's a reference-to-const. For that reason, C++1x, the next C++ version, introduce a new kind of reference, so-called *rvalue-references* which fixes that.

---

The *Microsoft Visual C++* compiler binds rvalues to references to non-const, but gives out a warning when doing that (you have to use at least warning level 4 for it to show up). That's unfortunate, because problems rise up when porting to other compilers that are more strict in Standard compliance.

Comment: Changing the operator to a const reference fixes the problem gracefully. Thanks for the info about rvalues.

I have no idea why the code compiled for anyone else. The project is intended for Windows... maybe they're all using a *cough* non-compiliant compiler. No idea.

Comment: litb: I think you mean "reference-to-const" in your sentence "Also, if you go by that, the parameter can't have called non-const member functions on it, because it's a reference-to-nonconst."

Comment: Matt: older versions of MS Visual C++ would incorrectly bind temporaries to ref-to-non-const.  I think this was fixed in MSVC++ 2005.

Answer (score 3):

My guess is that `EnhSimOutput& operator<< (setw& p);` passes by non-const reference, but the value 26 is "const" in the sense that it cannot be modified.  Try setting it to `EnhSimOutput& operator<< (const setw& p);`

or try

```
int nNumber = 26;  
enh::eout << enh::setw(nNumber);
```

Comment: -1, because the issue has nothing to do with 26 being a literal. The problem is that 'enh::setw(number)' is a temporary, and therefore can't be bound to a non-const reference.